# Who am I? Find out in order to survive

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

```
I could be the one that heals you
I could be the one that kills you
You might recognise me on paper but not my name
I was 11., 12. and currently 13.
I am an indicator that someone learned hard
I am often used in TV to make evil look smart
```

Who/What am I?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are:

> **THE DOCTOR** (from the BBC TV show *Doctor Who*)

*I could be the one that heals you*
*I could be the one that kills you*

> The job of many a *doctor* is to *heal*. However, in some parts of the world it is also legal for doctors to end life through euthanasia.

*You might recognise me on paper but not my name*

> If you see the words '**Doctor Who**' written out you might know this is a [BBC TV show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Who). However, if you heard the phrase said aloud, you would think somebody was struggling to identify a particular doctor...
>
>  <sub>EDIT: In comments the OP pointed out they had intended this line to be a reference to doctors' renown for having illegible handwriting, hence being unable to recognise their name as in *read their signature*.</sub>

*I was 11., 12. and currently 13.*

> In total, 13 actors have played The Doctor in the *Doctor Who* canon, since The Doctor possesses the ability to 'regenerate' and change his/her appearance whenever the scriptwriter requires! The current incumbent (the 13th) is Jodie Whitaker. (The 12th was Peter Capaldi, the 11th Matt Smith...)

*I am an indicator that someone learned hard*

> Somebody who can call themselves a qualified doctor can affix the title 'Dr' to the front of their name. This shows they have either completed medical school or done a PhD - both of which are huge academic endeavours.

*I am often used in TV to make evil look smart*

> How many bad guys in TV, film and literature can you think of who are called 'Dr so-and-so'?? Dr No, Dr Frankenstein, Dr Moreau, various mad scientists - I could go on. But in general, these evil characters give off an air of intelligence and shrewdness, in large part thanks to their title. Well, with the exception of [Dr Evil](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tg_TnFHK3wI) of course...! *(WARNING: YouTube video in link may contain the odd naughty word!)*

Comment: Yes totally! You literally got all the clues on point except the one "You might recognise me on paper but not my name" - that was intended to be a reference on the bad handwriting of doctors. Some say "Your handwriting is very bad, do you aim to be a doctor". So you can recognise a doctor on paper by his writing but not his name since you cannot identify the letters. I still like your explanation though. Very well done!

Comment: @Quotenbanane Ah yes, of course - I'll add that too for completenesd. Thanks!